# How use Portable.Licensing for encrypt All methods in a dll?

Tags: c#, licensing

I want to use Portable.Licensing library for create a license for my dll
but if license is invalid or expired throw an exception for any method 
and no one can use it

[Portable.Licensing Site](https://github.com/dnauck/Portable.Licensing)

How I can achieve to this purpose ? a license for working all methods

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can assert the license:

```
using Portable.Licensing.Validation;

var validationFailures = license.Validate()  
                            .ExpirationDate()  
                                .When(lic => lic.Type == LicenseType.Trial)  
                            .And()  
                            .Signature(publicKey)  
                            .AssertValidLicense();
```

then then loop thru all licenses validation failures and throw an exception if desired:

```
if (validationFailures.Any())
     throw new Exception(.....);
```